# PKIX path building failed: SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, wso2-api-manager, openshift-origin, pkix

I am using WSO2 API manager and keycloak servers for API gateway and user authentication. Both are running on Openshift 3.11. On the browser, while trying to redirect to a store page on wso2 apim getting below error. Also, I am using a self-signed certificate generared using keytool for both the servers and it is also imported into JVM cacerts respectively. Open JDK version is 1.8.

```
ERROR - WebAppManager org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (/store/jagg/jaggery_oidc_acs.jag#39)
```

I am getting fatal Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown in the ssl logs 
SSL Trace

```
WSO2 api manager serverlogs 
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -779209738 bytes = { 34, 29, 203, 199, 214, 88, 147, 174, 199, 184, 79, 68, 86, 150, 221, 45, 65, 169, 84, 10, 255, 155, 151, 74, 102, 245, 103, 39 }
Session ID:  {42, 139, 29, 172, 52, 46, 203, 207, 29, 65, 141, 230, 125, 206, 41, 206, 87, 139, 101, 118, 40, 54, 120, 240, 148, 225, 222, 95, 130, 19, 238, 225}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0xa:0xa, Unknown 0x13:0x1, Unknown 0x13:0x2, Unknown 0x13:0x3, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, Unknown 0xcc:0xa9, Unknown 0xcc:0xa8, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Unsupported extension type_43690, data: 
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=wso2carbon-customwso2.10.100.90.136.nip.io]
Unsupported extension type_23, data: 
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {unknown curve 10794, unknown curve 29, secp256r1, secp384r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:0c:02:68:32:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA256withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x4), SHA256withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x5), SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x6), SHA512withRSA, SHA1withRSA
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
Unsupported extension type_51, data: 00:29:2a:2a:00:01:00:00:1d:00:20:99:11:79:8f:3e:ca:9d:37:55:00:cf:54:3b:23:10:b1:71:93:92:06:81:ee:0f:b8:53:6e:e2:bf:23:b2:35:4e
Unsupported extension type_45, data: 01:01
Unsupported extension type_43, data: 0a:4a:4a:03:04:03:03:03:02:03:01
Unsupported extension type_27, data: 02:00:02
Unsupported extension type_47802, data: 00
Unsupported extension type_21, data: 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-11, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
%% Negotiating:  [Session-11, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1558345095 bytes = { 0, 101, 202, 146, 210, 87, 107, 127, 247, 125, 156, 64, 134, 222, 141, 197, 11, 134, 90, 77, 183, 201, 188, 129, 108, 229, 69, 60 }
Session ID:  {93, 226, 118, 135, 111, 45, 217, 124, 93, 2, 72, 71, 38, 116, 139, 207, 16, 91, 42, 171, 119, 141, 227, 122, 189, 253, 147, 133, 229, 78, 153, 32}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=wso2carbon-customwso2.10.100.90.136.nip.io, OU=Support, O=WSO2, L=Colombo, ST=Western, C=LK
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 24093749320119526217646893112163833209990474156688526832095621197039887367241482686643283752190553598539694041780318444455437473717327292475492934518259361370685860893170612648201871219684080088211608067291176086279564665228754086702863628019875085423939062501065434105176143021495735869756161068709421567662413327234744251786230141003775511653021592979156235418584147136970244449197736325946516688826096049982279922898011020940527605742056019219863317365450049812143562126732358220198845931195726312193213776283582315871213628750612092393628809426922961515763709022778700015014889582902887232786822789004520865673971
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Nov 29 07:02:23 UTC 2019,
               To: Mon Nov 26 07:02:23 UTC 2029]
  Issuer: CN=wso2carbon-customwso2.10.100.90.136.nip.io, OU=Support, O=WSO2, L=Colombo, ST=Western, C=LK
  SerialNumber: [    24b1e8e1]
Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: D0 AC 4E 4A 58 57 29 25   C2 C4 0B 1A AD 3E 66 2E  ..NJXW)%.....>f.
0010: C1 8A EC 66                                        ...f
]
]
]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 1D 01 81 69 ED BF F6 10   F6 17 D4 F2 87 63 D5 A2  ...i.........c..
0010: 12 CF 1A 09 ED FA E5 E3   24 18 03 FF E0 3B 0C A5  ........$....;..
0020: 31 0C D8 4B C5 FB 61 10   61 F5 42 71 E3 52 2F 70  1..K..a.a.Bq.R/p
0030: 97 B8 1F 61 96 0C 5F DB   BA B5 A2 DF 42 79 E3 BA  ...a.._.....By..
0040: 3C A8 C0 9C A5 8C 70 F9   51 46 36 39 D6 5A AA D7  <.....p.QF69.Z..
0050: 6E DD F0 35 E0 D0 FC AA   78 C2 57 4D BC E8 B1 FB  n..5....x.WM....
0060: FF 03 C5 39 5B 06 8C FC   6F DA 42 B4 13 7D A9 14  ...9[...o.B.....
0070: 7B D2 5F A0 29 28 52 78   D8 F7 E7 2E 26 78 1C 4F  .._.)(Rx....&x.O
0080: 16 A8 6B 02 3B FA 40 F2   4B AD 03 7D D0 9A F9 94  ..k.;.@.K.......
0090: 7E A9 48 D4 B6 58 A9 61   4E F0 CF 9A B5 77 8C B7  ..H..X.aN....w..
00A0: 74 76 FF 24 F2 B5 98 EE   70 1E 04 48 6F 54 1B EC  tv.$....p..HoT..
00B0: 98 B8 7B B0 58 F3 11 F5   FB 2B 39 5C 3E 78 83 E5  ....X....+9\>x..
00C0: 86 2A 4A 83 D6 4C 8D 08   54 43 C3 57 5F C1 27 9A  .*J..L..TC.W_.'.
00D0: 31 E8 77 A9 0B 2B F3 25   CB 7A 30 CF 45 CA 80 2A  1.w..+.%.z0.E..*
00E0: 4A C2 AC 5C 79 8F 25 70   E8 20 11 FC B5 BC 3E 1D  J..\y.%p. ....>.
00F0: B4 B3 69 5D F9 2E 5C 83   AB 8F C3 1C A7 B1 5F F0  ..i]..\......._.
]
***
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 30783140126565731034039954914815296826962617090801880033831456830219573014758
  public y coord: 112055812426524440654969792257542967866103028528061549518876777480127240144881
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** ServerHelloDone
http-nio-9443-exec-17, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1375
http-nio-9443-exec-19, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-9443-exec-19, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, certificate_unknown
http-nio-9443-exec-19, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
http-nio-9443-exec-19, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
http-nio-9443-exec-19, called closeOutbound()
http-nio-9443-exec-19, closeOutboundInternal()
http-nio-9443-exec-19, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
http-nio-9443-exec-19, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are importing the right certificate? Seems to be that you are importing the wrong one or you are not using the cacerts that you think you are.

Please check both